# Export data distribution for multi-storage external table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Let's say I define an external table with multiple (say N) storage accounts (ADLS Gen2) associated with it as shown here:-

```
.create-or-alter external table my_external_table
(
section:string,
mypayload:string,
mypartition:datetime) 
kind=adl
partition by (mypartition:datetime = bin(mypartition, 1h) , section:string = section) 
pathformat = (datetime_pattern("yyyy/MM/dd/HH",mypartition) "/" section)
dataformat=parquet
( 
   h@'abfss://mycontainer@mystorage1.dfs.core.windows.net/datafolder;<storagekey>',
   h@'abfss://mycontainer@mystorage2.dfs.core.windows.net/datafolder;<storagekey>'
   .
   .
   h@'abfss://mycontainer@mystorageN.dfs.core.windows.net/datafolder;<storagekey>'
)
```

So when I export data to to this external table, how is the data distributed across all the N storage accounts? Is that a uniform distribution?

Comment: I experimented with this , it didn't turn out to be uniform (either in terms of number of rows or data size) for sure. It would be nice to get some insight into how ADX is determining this distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Containers are chosen at random for each exported blob with a uniform distribution, have you experienced non-uniform distribution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).